# Does Azure Maps have heatmap functionality like Google Maps

Tags: azure, azure-maps

We are investigating Azure Maps for an authenticated site where Google Maps would not be free and Azure maps would be easier from a billing perspective.

Heatmap would be one functionality we are interested in, like the one here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap. Is that available in Azure Maps?

Comment: What's with the downvoting? If I would have asked "How do I implement a heatmap with Azure Map", would that have satisfied the programming requirement?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted. I'm fine with this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet exposed, but is planned to be added soon.

**Update:**

Heatmaps are now available in Azure Maps. Reference docs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.layer.heatmaplayer?view=azure-iot-typescript-latest)

Here are some code samples:

- [Simple Heat Map](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?search=heat%20maps&sample=Simple%20Heat%20Map%20Layer)
- [Weighted Heat Map](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?search=heat%20maps&sample=Weighted%20Heat%20Map%20Layer)
- [Heat Map Layer Options](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?search=heat%20maps&sample=Heat%20Map%20Layer%20Options)

Comment: Feel free to send me an email at richbrun at microsoft dot com and I'll see if I can get you early access.